# How do I remove null Fields in message payload before publishing in kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

When I publish a payload to a kafka topic, if a particular field has a null value, or empty string, this field shows up in the payload when using MessageBuilder. I do want any of the fields that have null values in the message before I publish through kafkaTemplate. How can I filter them when I am using MessageBuilder and kafkaTemplate send method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the message builder or template.
It sounds like you might be using JSON to serialize the payload; in that case, you need to configure the JSON serialization for that - see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields for a tutorial.